# 3d vision sensor

Tags: ros, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I have question about ZED and ZR300:

1- can we use these sensor as Kinect like using depthimage-to-laserscan pkg  and provide 2d data for mapping.

2- If we cant use it like Kinect, I can get 2d Lidar to work with but for avoiding obstacle I think its a must 3d vision sensor please correct me if I am wrong.

3- now if we can use it like Kinect, I have a question now can we build the map autonomously and at the same time avoid obstacle.

I only used Kinect and autonomous navigation on premade map. that's why I am asking these question.

thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262769/3d-vision-sensor/) by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2017-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I can only answer question 1 and only about the ZED Cam: The ZED Cam gives you as output principally:

- two stereo images
- a depth image
- the camera pose

(according to the [ZED ROS wrapper doc](http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper?action=edit&line=17))

So I see no reason why it should not be possible to use the mentioned depthimage-to-laserscan pkg.

---

Originally posted by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) with karma: 60 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2017-05-30**:
thans for the answer, I will try it when I get it.